# Fluid Square Divs (Box-Sizing Issue)

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create a fluid div that remains square as the page is resized.
This is apparently possible by doing something like this.

```
div{
    width:25%
    padding-bottom:25%;
}
```

However this only works with the default box-model layout.
Is there a way to achieve this while using

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here is a code pen of my current html structure: [Code Pen](http://cdpn.io/DeiJm)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but by looking at your codepen example, the box is taller than it is wide when resized because of the text within it.

Comment: Is there a way to make the box disregard the text, and remain square while still being fluid?

Answer (score 0):

If editing the HTML is an option:

- Put the link text in a `span` with absolute positioning.
- Set `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` to `0`.

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/CEjF9/3/)

**HTML**

```
...
<a href="#"><span>Sed volutpat</span></a>
<a href="#"><span>Sed volutpat</span></a>
...
```

**CSS**

```
...
a {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    padding-bottom: 80%;
    ...
}
a span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    ...
}
```